# Error en la línea 7/19: ORA-00907: falta el paréntesis derecho

Tags: base-de-datos

Me da este error al momento de intentar crear la tabla y no sé realmente le por qué, estoy trabajando con oracle apex 18c

```
create table cliente (
    id numeric generated always AS IDENTITY(start with 1 increment by 1),
    nombre varchar(100) not null,
    apellido1 varchar(100) not null,
    apellido2 varchar(100),
    ciudad varchar(100),
    categoria int UNSIGNED
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para números enteros basta con usar **INT** o **NUMBER** el **UNSIGNED** no es necesario para tu caso en la columna ***categoria int UNSIGNED***.

```
CREATE TABLE cliente (
id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
nombre VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
apellido1 VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
apellido2 VARCHAR2(100),
ciudad VARCHAR2(100),
categoria NUMBER);
```

**NUMBER** puede manejar tanto números positivos como negativos, si quieres validar que solo sean numeros positivos puedes usar lo siguiente después de haber creado la tabla:

```
ALTER TABLE cliente ADD CONSTRAINT categoria_positive CHECK (categoria >= 0);
```